# Random query strings appearing when including scripts

Tags: javascript, query-string

On my website I am having issues with random query strings appearing when I include scripts on my webpage. I know it's not me as both Pingdom & Google Pagespeed have confirmed that I have random query strings, but the issue is why. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/randomfile.js"></script>
```

appears in developer tools of Chrome, Firefox, and IE as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/randomfile.js?_=1247543709724"></script>
```

Any pointers as in why this would be happening? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be a cachebusting version string. What server-side technology are you using to output the script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is some unique value (probably generated at time of page load) that is appeneded to the URL of the script. This prevents the script being cached, because on every page load the URL will be unique.

I can't say what is doing it without seeing your setup, but it's most probably one of the libraries you're using.

Comment: You were completely correct and pointed me into the right direction. jQuery was appending those to the end of the scripts, the following fixed it:
`$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:true
});`

Thank you:)

Comment: That number really does not look like a timestamp.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah on second look it's far too short. Good spot, amended.

Comment: Sorry that's my issue - at the time I didn't know it was a timestamp so I made up a random number. It is indeed a timestamp in the real world - I'll fix that now

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Whether a resource is cached is dependent on the HTTP response headers, not the presence or value of any query string parameters.

Comment: @RickViscomi The answer is correct. If the browser see's a new URL, it will load it from the server, whatever is cached won't be read.

Comment: Not reading from cache is very different from not being cached. Your answer incorrectly states that the query string will prevent the script file from being cached.

Answer (score 2):

If your source HTML does not include the query string, there would appear to be a server-side optimization tool rewriting your `src`s.

The reason why these query string values are good is for cache busting. JavaScript files generally change infrequently, making them good candidates for caching. But when you do change a JS file, you want to ensure that your users put the new file to use as opposed to the file in cache. So you update your `src` value to a new, unique URL. The browser treats this as a totally new resource and downloads it from the server, ignoring what is already in cache.